The GET method is not supported for route update_user. Supported methods: POST. when trying to validate()
im totally new in Laravel and Im facing a problem when i try to validate fields that are coming from a form, i "copied" the create template and function that is working but when i call my fuction store_updated_user, shows the error, if I comment the validation, the record is succesfully updated.
@include('layout.header')
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-col-md-offset-4">
              <p class="h1">Actualizar Usuario</p>
              <hr class="rounded">
              <form action="{{route('store_updated_user')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  @csrf
              
                  @if (Session::has('success'))
                      <div class="alert alert-success">
                          {{Session::get('success')}}
                      </div>
                  @endif
                  @if (Session::has('fail'))
                  <div class="alert alert-danger">
                      {{Session::get('fail')}}
                  </div>
              @endif
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id">ID Usuario</label>
                    <input type="text" name="idtoupdate" value="{{$usertoupdate->id }}" hidden>
                    <input type="text" name="id" value="{{$usertoupdate->id }}" disabled>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="name">Nombre</label>
                      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{ $usertoupdate->name , old('name') }}">
                      <span class="text-danger">
                          @error('name')
                              {{$message}}
                          @enderror
                      </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="last_name">Apellido Paterno</label>
                      <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" value="{{$usertoupdate->last_name , old('last_name')}}">
                      <span class="text-danger">
                          @error('last_name')
                              {{$message}}
                          @enderror
                      </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="m_last_name">Apellido Materno</label>
                      <input type="text" name="m_last_name" class="form-control" value="{{$usertoupdate->m_last_name , old('m_last_name')}}">
                      <span class="text-danger">
                          @error('m_last_name')
                              {{$message}}
                          @enderror
                      </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div> 
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">   
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="email">Email</label>
                      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="{{$usertoupdate->email , old('email')}}">
                      <span class="text-danger">
                          @error('email')
                              {{$message}}
                          @enderror
                      </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
               


                <div class="col-md-4">  
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="birth_date">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
                      <input type="date" name="birth_date" class="form-control" value="{{$usertoupdate->birth_date , old('birth_date')}}">
                      <span class="text-danger">
                          @error('birth_date')
                              {{$message}}
                          @enderror
                      </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="born_place">Lugar de Nacimiento</label>
                      <input type="text" name="born_place" class="form-control" value="{{$usertoupdate->born_place , old('born_place')}}">
                      <span class="text-danger">
                          @error('born_place')
                              {{$message}}
                          @enderror
                      </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="curp">CURP</label>
                      <input type="text" name="curp" class="form-control"  value="{{$usertoupdate->curp , old('curp')}}">
                      <span class="text-danger">
                          @error('curp')
                              {{$message}}
                          @enderror
                      </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="role">Tipo de usuario</label>
                      <select id="role" name="role" class="form-control">
                          @if($user_data->role == 1 )<option value="1" @if($usertoupdate->role == 1) selected  @endif>Administrador</option>@endif
                          @if($user_data->role == 1 )<option value="2" @if($usertoupdate->role == 2) selected  @endif>Cordinador</option>@endif
                          <option value="3" @if($usertoupdate->role == 3) selected  @endif>Maestro</option>
                          <option value="4" @if($usertoupdate->role == 4) selected  @endif>Alumno</option>
                        </select>
                      <span class="text-danger">
                      </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Actualizar Usuario</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                </div>
              </div>

              </form>
          </div>
      </div>

      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </div>

</body>
</html>

public function store_updated_user(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|unique:users,email',
        'birth_date' => 'required:date',
        'born_place' => 'required',
        'curp' => 'required|string|min:18|max:18',
    ]);

    return('validacion completada');

    /*
    $user_data = array();
    if(Session::has('loginId')){
        $user_data = User::where('id','=',Session::get('loginId'))->first();
    }
    $idtoupdate = $request->idtoupdate;
    $usertoupdate = array();
    $usertoupdate = DB::table('users')->where('id', $idtoupdate)->first();
    */
}

Route::controller(AdminController::class)->group(function() {
    Route::get('/dashboard','dashboard')->middleware('isLoggedIn');
    Route::get('/create_user','create_user')->middleware('isLoggedIn');
    Route::post('/registration-user','registerUser')->name('register-user');
    Route::get('/view_user', 'view_user')->middleware('isLoggedIn');
    Route::post('/update_user', 'update_user')->name('update_user');
    Route::post('/store_updated_user', 'store_updated_user')->name('store_updated_user');
    Route::get('/test','test')->middleware('isLoggedIn');
});

I want to validate the fields that are coming from my update_user form.

Same error is apearing if i uncomment the bellow lines
if($result){
                //return back()->with('success','You have registered successfully.');
            } else {
              
                //return back()->with('fail','Something wrong!');
            }

feels like a configuration on my dev server

I think you should first understand how CRUD functions works in Laravel. Store is usually an action for creating records, but for updating one you should use update, and a put route. Then in your edit form your method is actually correct, but you should add @method('PUT') after @csrf.

I just realized that I lost a big point. Your error message comes from the fact that you are calling a post route  Route::post('/update_user', 'update_user')->name('update_user');  via GET method. Are you trying to show the edit form?

Thanks for reply.... i have first a view with all my users, each user have their own  were if send the id to update to the update_user form from there i submit the form that call store_updated_user.....

i used dd to debug and found that the problem is inside the function validate() that is crashing when needs to return a error, but i dont know how to solve.

$validated = $request->validate([
'name' => 'required',
'last_name' => 'required',
'email' => 'required',
//'email' => 'required|unique:users,email',
'birth_date' => 'required:date',
'born_place' => 'required',
'curp' => 'required|string|min:18|max:18',
]);
if, i uncomment the commented row, it show an error, same when i send null values to any of the required fields, otherwise, it pass!

If I comment the validation records are updated successfully.

It appears that the issue is using post instead get, I changed and everything is working fine now, I need to understand how validate() return the values to work with post
